# Tikz - Add text near matrix entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have this column array created using a `matrix`:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
      \matrix (F) [% 
        matrix of nodes, 
        nodes={
          rectangle,
          minimum height=6mm,
          minimum width=6mm,
          anchor=center,
          inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
        }
      ] at (0, 0) { 0 \\ 3 \\ 7 \\ 13 \\ 14 \\ };
      \draw (F-1-1.north west) -- 
            (F-1-1.north east) --
            (F-5-1.south east) --
            (F-5-1.south west) -- 
            (F-1-1.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I add labels to each row entries such that I can recreate this pictures:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't need a sledge-hammer like TiKZ to do that. I suggest you take a look at the `blkarray` and `bigdelim` packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can place nodes around your matrix.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
      \matrix (F) [% 
        matrix of nodes, 
        nodes={
          rectangle,
          minimum height=6mm,
          minimum width=6mm,
          anchor=center,
          inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
        }
      ] at (0, 0) { 0 \\ 3 \\ 7 \\ 13 \\ 14 \\ };
      \draw (F-1-1.north west) rectangle (F-5-1.south east);
      \foreach \c [count=\i from 1] in {$\$_i$,A,C,G,T}
            \node[left=3pt of F-\i-1]{\c};
      \node[above=3pt of F-1-1]{$F$};   
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This way you can also draw around your matrix to make what you want, using nodes coordinates and anchors.
[image: First one]

#### EDIT

There are many ways to draw the bracket on the left, but using nodes names, you can do it pretty easily:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
      \matrix (F) [% 
        matrix of nodes, 
        nodes={
          rectangle,
          minimum height=6mm,
          minimum width=6mm,
          anchor=center,
          inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
        }
      ] at (0, 0) { 0 \\ 3 \\ 7 \\ 13 \\ 14 \\ };
     \draw (F-1-1.north west) rectangle (F-5-1.south east);

      \draw ([xshift=-4pt]F-1-1.north west) --++ (-2pt,0) |- ([xshift=-4pt]F-3-1.south west) node[left,pos=0.25]{$A$};
      \node[above=3pt of F-1-1]{\textit{last}};     
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Second one]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have only one last question: How can I group some entry like the second picture?

Comment: I edited my post to give a solution for the second part of the question.